# How do I install toolchains in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode15

The [Xcode documentation](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/dev05f62dd59) suggests that when you install a toolchain in either the `/Library/Developer/Toolchains/` or `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains/` folders, that you will see the toolchains shown in the “Components” tab in “Settings”. I do not see it there, but instead see a “Platforms” tab instead? Where is it?

[image: xcode settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is under the “Xcode” menu. The “Toolchains” option only appears once you have installed a toolchain (i.e., copied or added a symbolic link) in either `/Library/Developer/Toolchains/` or `~/Library/Developer/Toolchains/`.

[image: menu]

Comment: FWIW, I have submitted feedback to Apple to update the Xcode documentation.